# why is this not working - ruby koans

Tags: ruby

I came up with the following solution for a koan.

```
# and
#   about_triangle_project_2.rb
#
def triangle(a, b, c)

   driehoek = Array.new[ a, b, c].sort

  raise (TriangleError), "length cannnot be 0 or lesser" if (driehoek[0] <= 0) 
  raise (TriangleError), "impossible triangle" if (driehoek[0] + driehoek[1] < driehoek[2])

 return :equilateral if ((a == b) and (b == c))
 return :isosceles if (((a == b) and (b != c)) or 
                   ((a != b) and (b == c)) or 
                   ((a == c) and (a != b)))
  return :scalene  if ((a !=b) and (b != c))
end

# Error class used in part 2.  No need to change this code.
class TriangleError < StandardError
end
```

But now when triangle [2,2,2] is used I see this error message :

```
The answers you seek...
 wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Please meditate on the following code:
  ./triangle.rb:18:in `[]'
  ./triangle.rb:18:in `triangle'
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ?

Roelof

Comment: The response points to an error. Please next time indicate what line in the code is #18. You also do not need to provide the whole code, only parts that are relevant to questin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how you are creating the array. `new` is a method and you'll need to use `parens ()`. Change this:

```
driehoek = Array.new[ a, b, c].sort
```

To this and it should work:

```
driehoek = Array.new([a, b, c]).sort
```

Comment: or `driehoek = [a, b, c]`. You were doing it dubbelop.